# How to securely encrypt password

Tags: php, codeigniter

First and foremost, I want to iterate that I'm not asking how to HASH a password (such as salting / bcrypt / etc).  For every other project I've done, I've always hashed / salted the passwords but in this case I need to regain the password temporarily.

Basically, I need to store a password in my DB and then have it be accessible again.  In codeigniter (the framework I'm using), they use mcrypt as well as a key (which they suggest should be 32-characters long).  Would this suffice?

**EDIT**:

The reason for asking: I need to be able to send out mission-critical sensitive PDFs to users and want to password protect them (ideally with the same password).

After a discussion with people on SO and off, I've come to the conclusion that you should NEVER encrypt a password and always hash / salt it.  Think of how many people use the same password / email for different services.  Therefore, I've come to the conclusion that IF you DO need to encrypt an item that you should use a separate PIN or other non-essential item.

However, even though I'm going to go the pin route and keep the passwords hashed, I still am very curious as to how you would *theoretically* go about this problem.

Comment: Without being a condescending snob (which I know these kinds of comments can often sound like... sorry ahead of time), why do you need to regain the user's password? Typically that indicates a design flaw that should be got around some other way.

Comment: EDITED
haha, no problem.  Basically, I'm sending out PDFs to all the users in the database once a day.  As this contains critical information that should not be shared, I want to have the PDF be password protected by their own password.  Maybe there is another way around it?

Edit:  I should also add that viewing the PDF on a webpage is not always possible.

Comment: @corsiKa condescending snob.. this is a good question

Comment: Not every problem allows for one-way hashes.  Think of solutions where you need to capture credentials or passwords for other uses, like in this case or a password manager.  You need a way to get back to the original data.  @corsiKa, it is not always a "design flaw".

Comment: Use the last 4 of their social, their middle name, or some other non-critical piece of data for the PDF password.  Request it in a separate field.  Encrypting their site password in a manner that allows retrieval is very inadvisable (as @corsiKa mentioned, it's a design flaw).  Passwords should always use a 1-way hash.

Comment: @TheSmose, but if I ask for their social (or last 4 digits of their credit card), that puts them at another security risk if the DB is ever taken.  Wouldn't a password be much more advisable than having their email and last 4 digits of their SSN?  If I had that, I'd instantly make requests to all financial institutions asking for their password.

Comment: I'm making a comment because it doesn't answer the actual question, but rather the business problem: What I would do is generate a password when the pdf is requested, then send the user an email or other notification containing the one-time use password. You never need to store the password in the database; if they need the password after they deleted the email (which you should encourage them to do) they can re-download it and get another password. This doesn't address the issue of how to securely make a retrievable password, so I'm not making it an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as long as you keep the SALT value secret.

**UPDATE:** seems people do not happy with  simple answers. by using `mcrypt` extensions, you can encrypt your data with a specific secret value `SALT`. If people do not know the SALT, they can't decrypt the value.

Example:

```
<?php 
    define('SALT', 'whateveryouwant'); 

    function encrypt($text) 
    { 
        return trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, SALT, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND)))); 
    } 

    function decrypt($text) 
    { 
        return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, SALT, base64_decode($text), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))); 
    } 
?>
```

Of course, if you want extra security, consider using Public Key Infrastructure.

Comment: Out of curiosity since I have very little knowledge in encryption, what other products / services are out there and why would mcrypt be the best choice?  I don't want to waste your time, but was just hoping for a quick one or two paragraphs if you don't mind.

Comment: Upvoted this.  However, to OP, keep in mind that this is NOT secure enough for site passwords.  If the system storing your passwords is compromised, it's safe to assume the salt is compromised, too.